# JS OAuth 2.0 on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1

So, I'm trying to create a Gitter client for Windows Phone and to do so I need to use Bearer OAuth on their API. This process seems to result in a redirection to a gitter webpage (to get access tokens) and then it redirects to a web page specififed by my application. However obviously an APP is not a web page, so how am I supposed to get the returned temporary access token to use the API?

I've read a little bit about using `ms-app://<security identifier>` but it's all very fuzzy and little to no information seems to be about using it without using `c#`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** I just noticed this has been asked here [oAuth 2.0 in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665498/oauth-2-0-in-windows-phone-8-1) but hasn't been awnsered. Sorry for the duplication.

Comment: How is project progrssing? Is this project open source? Can I contribute?

Comment: @AleksandarToplek It is! However, the repo is private as of now because it's not entirely done but if you want to don't hesitate to contact me via email and I'll unprivate it (it's open source). It's about halfway done, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it was under my nose the whole entire time!

You can use `Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue(startURI, endURI);`

(docs are mainly c# but here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631755.aspx)

i.e

```
  var redirect_uri = 'ms-app://<sid>';
  var client_id = '<client id>';

  // testing 
  var requestUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(
    'https://<site>/?client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri
  );

  Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue(requestUri, Windows.Foundation.Uri(redirect_uri));

  app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind == activation.ActivationKind.webAuthenticationBrokerContinuation) {
      //take oauth response and continue login process
      console.log(args.detail.webAuthenticationResult);
    }
    //Handle normal activiation...(hidden)
  });
```

source: http://blog.stevenedouard.com/andcontinue-methods-for-windows-universal-apps/